# Autolayout - Freeform View

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I have a UIViewController with a UIView in which I am adding UIViewController views in as subviews. i.e

```
UIViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[my_view_in_xib addSubview:vc.view];
```

The ViewControllers view and the subviews have AutoLayout enabled. The top level does resize correctly (changing background color to red) I can see it is the right size. However in the subviews in the XIB file I have set the view to be "Freeform" or "None" on the "Size" and pinned the tables to top & bottom and made them pin on the width but the height does not seem to auto resize?

Any suggestions?

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you resize, you should send `setNeedsLayout` to the superview. Otherwise, the layout system will not recalculate the frames of the subviews.

In Apple's [own words](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW135):

> View resizing primarily occurs when the orientation of your
>   application’s interface changes but it may happen at other times as
>   well. For example, calling the setNeedsLayout method forces your view
>   to update its layout.